# can i get unique values of the aggregated field in mysql query which uses group by for another field

Tags: mysql

here is a table

```
id | year
1   2020
2   2020
3   2020
1   2019
2   2019
3   2019
```

I tried to group via year and the result i am getting is

```
id | year
1   2020
1   2019
```

but i need  to get distinct values for id

**Expected:**

```
id | year
1   2020
2   2019
```

(or)

```
id | year
1   2020
3   2019
```

i tried with this mysql query

`select * from table group by year`

Comment: *but i need to get distinct values for id* why? What is the logic behind these results?

Comment: Formulate the criteria which will define what id value must be returned for each year value - without "or", "maybe", etc. I.e. any man must obtain the same result while using this rule over the same data.

Comment: @forpas I don't want id to repeat for more than one year after grouping. Assume this table to be obtained after various joins from other tables

Comment: So any result like: `1 2020, 2 2019` or `1 2020, 3 2019` or `2 2020, 3 2019` would do?

Comment: yes any combination is allowed until one id is not used for more than a year @forpas

Answer (score 0):

This might be tricky to do without using analytic functions, but if you are using MySQL 8+, here is one way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, year, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY year) dr,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, year
FROM cte
WHERE dr = rn;
```

### Demo

For an explanation, here is a query on the full CTE without any `WHERE` clause:

[image: screen capture of CTE]

Note that each block of year records has `dr` numbered from 1 onwards, and within each block of year records the `rn` column is numbered from 1 onwards.  We retain rows where the row number and dense rank are identical.

Comment: Hey Tim thanks for you contribution but this will not help in my case as i am using mysql 5

Comment: If you have requirements like this often, then I strongly suggest upgrading to MySQL 8+.  MySQL 5 and earlier will only be officially supported for so long.